# How can i receive result concatenating dataframe and character string in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x

- emp.csv file

> 

```
    index   empno   ename   job mgr hiredate    sal comm    deptno
>     0,  7839,   KING,   PRESIDENT,  0,  1981-11-17,     5000,   0,  10
>     1,  7698,   BLAKE,  MANAGER,    7839,   1981-05-01, 2850,   0,  30
>     2,  7782,   CLARK,  MANAGER,    7839,   1981-05-09, 2450,   0,  10
>     3,  7566,   JONES,  MANAGER,    7839,   1981-04-01, 2975,   0,  20
>     4,  7654,   MARTIN, SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-09-10, 1250,   1400,   30
>     5,  7499,   ALLEN,  SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-02-11, 1600    300,    30
>     6,  7844,   TURNER, SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-08-21, 1500,   0,  30
>     7,  7900,   JAMES,  CLERK,      7698,   1981-12-11, 950,    0,  30
>     8,  7521,   WARD,   SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-02-23, 1250,   500,    30
>     9,  7902,   FORD,   ANALYST,    7566,   1981-12-11, 3000,   0,  20
>     10, 7369,   SMITH,  CLERK,      7902,   1980-12-09, 800,    0,  20
>     11, 7788,   SCOTT,  ANALYST,    7566    1982-12-22, 3000,   0,  20
>     12, 7876,   ADAMS,  CLERK,      7788,   1983-01-15, 1100,   0,  20
>     13, 7934,   MILLER, CLERK,      7782,   1982-01-11, 1300,   0,  10
```

Using the below code, I can get the below result.

- code :

> ```
> import csv
> import sys
>
> import pandas as pd
> import dateutil
>
> username = input(' Enter the ename ')
>
> with open("D:\R data\emp2.csv", 'r') as f:
>      reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
>      for row in reader:
>           if username == row[1]: 
>               print (row[1],' has ', int(row[5]) * 12')
> ```

result :
           KING  has  60000

I want to get this result by using pandas.

- code using pandas :

  ```
  import csv
  import sys

  import pandas as pd
  import dateutil

  # Load data from csv file
  emp = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("D:\R data\emp.csv")
  # Convert date from string to date times
  emp['hiredate'] = emp['hiredate'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse, dayfirst=True)


  empresult = pd.concat( [emp['ename'],emp['sal']*12],axis=1)


  print( empresult )
  ```

How can I receive the below result by concatenating dataframe and string in pandas?

```
result :
           KING  has  60000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\ophir\Test\stackoverflow\emp.csv", sep=',?\s*')
username = input(' Enter the ename ')
print(username, ' has ', df['sal'][df['ename'] == username].values[0] * 12)
```

The warnings you'll get are because of your non-consistent CSV format. A consistent CSV format uses the same delimiters for the headers and the values.
For example, if you'll add commas to the headers like:

```
index,   empno,   ename,   job, mgr, hiredate,    sal, comm,    deptno
```

then you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\ophir\Test\stackoverflow\emp.csv", sep=',\s*', engine='python')
username = input(' Enter the ename ')
print(username, ' has ', int(df['sal'][df['ename'] == username].values[0]) * 12)
```

without warnings.

I manually got rid of the sign `<` in the start of every line of values in your csv file.